# Synchronize webdav network drive with a folder on my PC or onedrive

Tags: sync, webdav

How can I synchronize my uni webdav network drive with a folder on my PC or onedrive without using a third party software

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this free software works fine for me and it can sync any two (or more) folders including network folders. [Download here](http://www.freefilesync.org/)